# meaning of "criminal enforcement"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

consider:

> "I think the rule is ill-conceived and that it seriously fetters perfectly legitimate methods of **criminal enforcement**".

I know meaning of the both,  *enforcement* and *criminal*. However, I cant figure out what the combination "criminal enforcement" conveys?

Moreover, I do know what **law enforcement** means. It means to do certain efforts making sure a system of law is obeyed. But, I have no idea about the definition of "**criminal enforcement**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's a program that enforces the nation's laws by investigating cases, collecting evidence, conducting forensic analyses and providing legal guidance to assist in the prosecution of criminal conduct that threatens people's health and the environment.*

You might want to see this

https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/criminal-enforcement-overview

Comment: Welcome mate 

Answer (score 1):

In this context, [criminal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criminal) means "relating to laws that describe crimes rather than to laws about a person's rights".

Criminal enforcement is therefore the part of law enforcement that deals with criminal matters such as murder, theft, and embezzlement, rather than those relating to rights, for example equal opportunity legislation.